# Flutter drive: How to only run one group or test

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing, flutter-test

So in the [introduction to integration testing](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) you're supposed to run your tests with

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart
```

However I can't find anything about running only a specific group or test.

```
flutter drive --help
```

also doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Although it seems there's no `out of the box` method / way to run only a group or specific test, we can achieve that using [flutter_gherkin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gherkin) package. This uses combination of gherkin and cucumber framework and has tags that we can specify tests that we want to run.
You can read more about it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gherkin#tags).

Basically, in the configuration file that package provides, you specify something like below:

```
..targetAppPath = "test_driver/app.dart"
..tagExpression = "@smoke"
..exitAfterTestRun = true;
```

And run the test from terminal like below:

`dart test_driver/app_test.dart --tags @smoke`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can add a `--feature` option to the test run

on app_test.dart

```
  var parser = ArgParser();
  parser.addOption('feature');
  var results = parser.parse(arguments);

  final config = FlutterTestConfiguration()
    ..features = [Glob("test_driver/features/" + results["feature"])]

....
```

then when running the tests you can specify `--feature your.feature`

Comment: What is `FlutterTestConfiguration` and where should I put this code? thanks